# Calculate duration between entries and exit - Code optimisation

Tags: r

I have some data with:

- An unique identifier
- An action (entry or exit)
- A time stamp
- A building ID
  and some other columns.

I am trying to calculate the time spent into a building based on the entry, the exit, the building id and the unique identifier (a car number).

Right now, I sort my dataframe by the unique ID, and then the date, and I apply this algorithm:

```
    For each row {
        if row.type = 'entry' and nextRow.type = 'exit' and row.uid = nextRow.uid {
        Calculate time difference and add this data to another df.
        }
    }
```

It takes some time to run although I have only 6000 rows... 
I am not very familiar with R and I think there are ways to accelerate this...

Code is as below:

```
# Sort rows: 
BldActivity <- BldActivity[order(BldActivity$UniqueId, BldActivity$DateOfEvent),]


df = data.frame(NULL)
DurationOfStay <- data.frame(NULL) 

for(i in 1:nrow(BldActivity)) {
    row <- BldActivity[i,]
    # do stuff with row
    if(row$Type == 'entry') {
        rowNext <- BldActivity[i+1,] 
        if(!is.na(rowNext$Type)) {
            if(rowNext$Type == 'exit' && row$UniqueId == rowNext$UniqueId)
            {
                        newRow <- data.frame( Entry_DateOfEvent = row$DateOfEvent,
                                        Exit_DateOfEvent  = rowNext$DateOfEvent,

                                        BuildingID = row$BuildingID,
                                        BuildingName = row$`Building Name`,
                                        UniqueId = row$UniqueId,
                                        DurationOfStay = difftime(rowNext$DateOfEvent, row$DateOfEvent, units="mins")
                                        )

                    DurationOfStay <- rbind(DurationOfStay,newRow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please point me to possible improvements?

Here is an input example:

```
DateOfEvent Type    UniqueId    BuildingID  Building Name
2019/03/22 09:15:43 entry   04352e5b6051c311048a5803f8716700    1e98f5c0e699    Building 2
2019/03/22 09:51:45 exit    04352e5b6051c311048a5803f8716700    1e98f5c0e699    Building 2
2019/03/22 10:31:28 entry   066b9a3995acd495318ad70e0d876f00    062e933d6b9f    Building 1
2019/03/22 11:15:02 exit    066b9a3995acd495318ad70e0d876f00    062e933d6b9f    Building 1
2019/03/22 11:11:42 entry   0e027aba359aaecbe8fe3eaf5a1bbb00    062e933d6b9f    Building 1
2019/03/22 14:44:27 exit    0e027aba359aaecbe8fe3eaf5a1bbb00    062e933d6b9f    Building 1
2019/03/22 09:55:03 entry   1747dbaef11176b9ab90f2cfbf056210    1e98f5c0e699    Building 2
2019/03/22 18:13:08 exit    1747dbaef11176b9ab90f2cfbf056210    1e98f5c0e699    Building 2
2019/03/21 14:23:53 entry   3e0d2c4b1b159a24f4dc5fa084b59f00    1e98f5c0e699    Building 2
2019/03/21 15:36:31 exit    3e0d2c4b1b159a24f4dc5fa084b59f00    1e98f5c0e699    Building 2
```

The output is just the column values for IN/OUT and the calculated duration.

Thanks

Philippe

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example along with an expected output based on that?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I've just added an example of input. (Only 10 rows though). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(BldActivity)
DurationOfStay <- dcast(BldActivity, UniqueId + BuildingID + `Building Name` ~ Type, value.var = "DateOfEvent")
DurationOfStay[, DurationOfStay := difftime(exit, entry, units="mins"), ]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. That's really cool but I came across another issue (Explained in next answer).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your code, it looks very promising.
I do have 2 problems though:

First, there was an issue with the aggregation function which throws the error:

> Aggregating function(s) should take vector inputs and return a single value (length=1).

I solved this by adding an aggregation function

```
fun.aggregate = function(x) { 
   lubridate::as_datetime(ifelse(Type == 'entry', min(x), max(x)))
}
```

I have also added a identifier to group the entries/exit based on the unique id, the building id and and the type (Entry/Exit)

Here is the new code:

```r
setDT(BldActivity)
BldActivity[, ID_Stay := seq_len(.N), by=list(UniqueId, BuildingID, Type)]
DwellTime <- dcast(BldActivity, UniqueId + BuildingID + `Building Name` ~ Type, value.var = "DateOfEvent", 
fun.aggregate = function(x) {
    lubridate::as_datetime(ifelse(Type == 'entry', min(x), max(x)))},
  fill = 0)
DurationOfStay[, DurationOfStay := difftime(exit, entry, units="mins"), ]
```

But I have very weird values... The reason is that if I have 2 entries and no exits in between, the whole sequence is messed up.

Here is an example:
[image: example]

Thanks

Philippe